# Selenium RC - Error: Could not find or load main class jar

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, runtime-error

I'm trying to run FIREFOX selenium IDE generated file in GOOGLE CHROME.

Below is a step by step description of what the problem is and what I have tried (unsuccessfully so far) to fix it.

**Environment**

```
Selenium IDE – installed**strong text**
Selenium RC – installed
Java version 1.7.0.05  - installed
```

**What I'm trying to Do:**

Running an FIREFOX IDE Generated Test in GOOGLE CHROME
Steps

```
(1) Following three .htm files created using FIREFOX
a.  google_for_selenium_rc.htm
b.  google_for_testing.htm
c.  visit_google_videos

(2) Created suite.htm file (see attached)

(3) Run the following command in cmd:

java –jar selenium-server.jar –htmlSuite “C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe¬” “http://www.google.com.au” 
“C:\Users\shelleymoudgil\Documents\KB\Selenium\SeleniumIDE\suite.htm” 
“C:\Users\shelleymoudgil\Documents\KB\Selenium\SeleniumIDE\results.htm”
```

**Expected**

```
(4) Script successfully executed in GOOGLE CROME
```

**Actual**

```
(5) Following Error displayed:
```

Error:

```
  Could not find or load main class ûjar
```

**Solutions tried so far**

- Added C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\ to PATH
- Added C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin to PATH
- Added C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\ to PATH

I'm new to java and selenium. I'm stuck for the past 1 day. Can somebody guide and advise a possible solution or what I might be doing wrong.

Thanks
Americain

Comment: Selenium RC requires that you write a java client (exported from the IDE) that makes calls to the RC library, which interacts with the server.  I think you can only run saved HTMl files from the IDE.  Go read ALL the documentation carefully.

Comment: Might help to maybe use http://pastebin.com and paste 1 of your Selenium IDE scripts that you exported.

Comment: hi sircasalot - i have pasted one  of the IDE generated .htm files on pastebin.com. see the link - http://pastebin.com/dx0mHNTK

Comment: @Americain, try again.  you tagged this as Java, I assume that you are using Java with Selenium RC.   You exported a Java version of your selenium IDE script. Paste that ;)

Answer (score 15):

Just from the error message, it looks like your `-jar` argument has something other than `-` as the first character, probably an en-dash.  It would then interpret `–jar` as a class to search for on the class path.  Attempting this yields the same error message for me, modulo whatever encoding transformation is happening to the error message on your system.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this just helped me understand a weird customer error.

Comment: For what it is worth, this was being caused by something happening in the copy and paste process. If you delete the - and retype this works

Comment: Thanks llasram, its a old post but it did help me

Answer (score -1):

Download this Jar file from the below link and paste it on the desktop.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=selenium-server-standalone-2.28.0.jar&can=2&q=

then type the following in the command prompt and run this jar.

> cd desktop
>   java -jar typejarname

after this the jar will start running.
now execute the code and see whether it is working or not.

Comment: This is not the cause of the problem. Did you not read [llasram's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14634301/474189) before posting?